# copying database from app to another app on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

we are using Heroku as our Cloud platform service
Now I have 3 apps 1 as production and the other two as staging, development.
 I made some changed in staging app and I need to copy the database (Postgres) from production to staging.
I found some guidelines in Heroku documentation but it's not clear.
can any one share his experience with me?
the database reach 25 GB Now

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends. I see two ways:

1. [heroku backups / restore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups): just use the last backup you have, or create a new one, then restore it to the staging server.
2. [forking the database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork): on the staging app, delete the postgres addon, and recreate it as a fork (aka copy) of the production server. The `--fast` option makes it even faster when the data doesn't have to be 100% up-to-date.

Since 25 GB is already over the recommended size for normal Heroku backups (20 GB), I would recommend going for option 2.

(though we are using Heroku backups for a 200GB database without any issues).